# rastertogutenprint5.3 not available

Tags: debian, cups

I installed the new Debian 10, and now the printer (Canon MG2500) doesn't work.
The error is "the file /usr/libs/cups/filter/rastertogutenprint.5.3 not available: no such file or directory".
But the file is there!
How can i solve that?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like [https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61805](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61805).
The path to the file [should be](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/printer-driver-gutenprint/filelist) `/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertogutenprint.5.3` ("lib" without "s"). Does removing and readding the printer in CUPS solve it?

Comment: I'm trying now for the first time, with the web interface of cups, but it request me username and password... Did I need to register?

Comment: Try your normal username + password or username "root" and its password. It should work without any configuration.

Comment: tried, root+password, it works and now the printer work. Problem solved, many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You probably need to install the package `printer-driver-gutenprint`, for example from the command line:

> sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint

Comment: This solved the problem for me

Comment: Bacon saved!!1!

Comment: This was also a solution on debian 11, it got removed during the upgrade. Looking at dpkg.log, it seems "autoremove" triggered it, it seems that it is not recommended to cups anymore.